# Is there a way to change column to foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have an existing column `project_id` inside a table called contents. It is supposed to be a foreign_key that references a project in projects table. However, whoever set up the database created the contents table without setting project_id as foreign_key.

I tried to create a migration as:

```
def change
    add_reference :contents, :project
end
```

But this tries to add a column `project_id` which already exists.

My Question is, is there a way (using migration) to change the column `project_id` to foreign_key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails 5+ allows you to add `foreign_key` [constraints using migration](https://devdocs.io/rails~5.0/activerecord/connectionadapters/schemastatements#method-i-add_foreign_key)

```
add_foreign_key :contents, :projects, column: :project_id, #primary_key: "id"
```

Aside of that, You do not need foreign key constraints for ActiveRecord to correctly map the relationships in migration, i.e `foreign_key` constraint can be set explicitly at model level too. To make faster retrieval [add `indexing`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index) on `project_id` using migration

Example-

```
class Content < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project, class_name: 'Project', :foreign_key => "project_id"
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :contents, class_name: 'Content', :foreign_key => "project_id",  :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Comment: I was looking for method 1. I knew about method 2 (via model). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can try with

```
add_foreign_key :contents, :projects, column: :project_id
```

for more details you can refer [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key)